# JSF permanent redirect using a bean on a preRenderView event

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Is there a way to permanently redirect to a page on preRenderEvent view using faces-config navigation?

For example, after login it will redirect on a page and on that page I need to know the role of a user so that I can redirect him to the correct page.

I'm using this to redirect:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:event listener="#{loginRedirectBean.redirect}" type="preRenderView"></f:event>
</f:metadata>

public void redirect() throws IOException {
    if (identity.isLoggedIn()) {
        if(hasRole("admin")) {
            ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
            context.redirect("faces.admin");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since faces-config navigation. I've just used a file given a role.

```
public void redirect() throws IOException {
    String redirectUrl = "login.jsf";
    if (identity.isLoggedIn()) {
        try {
            User user = ((PicketlinkUser) identity.getAccount()).getUser();
            if (user.hasRole(Role.ROLE_ADMIN)) {
                redirectUrl = "pages/secured/" + Role.ROLE_ADMIN + "/index.jsf";
            } else if (user.hasRole(Role.ROLE_BRIDE)) {
                redirectUrl = "pages/secured/" + Role.ROLE_BRIDE + "/index.jsf";
            } else if (user.hasRole(Role.ROLE_VENDOR)) {
                redirectUrl = "pages/secured/" + Role.ROLE_VENDOR + "/index.jsf";
            } else if (user.hasRole(Role.ROLE_COLLABORATOR)) {
                redirectUrl = "pages/secured/" + Role.ROLE_COLLABORATOR + "/index.jsf";
            } else {
                log.info("user={} has no valid role?", user);
                redirectUrl = "index.jsf";
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            log.error("no role?={}", e.getMessage());
        }
    } else {
        log.error("isNotLoggedIn, redirect to login.");
    }

    ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    context.redirect(redirectUrl);
}
```

Comment: This does not send a permanent redirect (301), but this sends a temporary redirect (302).

Answer (score 2):

You should so make use of "if else" statements based on the user role :

```
public void redirect(){
    ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    if (context.isUserInRole("admin"){
        context.redirect("adminpage");
    }
    else if (context.isUserInRole("user"){
        context.redirect("userpage");
    }
          // other possible roles
    else context.redirect("homepage");
}
```

*Unrelated :* In order to avoid firing double requests to the server whenever a user is logging in, I suggest to transfer that logic to be implemented within the method `redirect()`, to the method responsible of user logging with "if else" statements and with  a `String` returning outcome (*without the need to redirect manually as above*) to specify the right page name to redirct to depending on the user role in "if" instruction.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Actually that's what I did, sorry for the confusion but my question really is how to permanently redirect using faces-config. Unfortunately I can't redirect using the real loginController because I'm limited by picketlink library.

Comment: This means that `context.redirect("faces.somepage")` is not working ?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't redirect using a navigation rule. But when the value is an existing file it did.

Comment: So, why don't you use the files' names as the method parameter: `redirect("adminpage.xhtml")` ?

Comment: The problem with that is I navigate to the same file several times, my concern is if for some reason I have to change the physical path then I have to find all the method that navigates to that file.

Comment: So, that's why you'd like to use `faces-config` ? is it working ?

Comment: Let us see this config file.